# how to store for loop result to dataframe with if next condition

Tags: r, for-loop

I am quite new to R so apologize if I am asking something obvious.
I am trying to do a for loop for 143,635 loops. But in the loop, there are some conditions where I skip my loop.

Here is my code below
(~~~ are some codes for the loop)

```
j=1
result<-NULL

for(j in 1:143635)  
{~~~ 
if(nrow(OD_Routetable)<2) next 

~~
result1<-(prd_v==test$route)/nrow(test)*100

result<-rbind(result,result1)

}
```

is there a way I can save my for loop results into a data frame of 143,635 rows while filling the data frame with value "100" for the skipped loops?
would if else be more usefull?

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use ```if``` and ```else```?

Comment: @Ilkyun Im  no, maybe that could be my solution i just wanted to perform the loop with some skipping process. thanks. so using if and else allows me to save value "100" for the ones i skipped and perform the loop for the rest?

Comment: It would be helpful if you create a small reproducible example and show expected output for the same. Create something which we can test on our system and verify the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `for` loop like below?

```
result<-c()

for(j in 1:143635)  
{~~~ 
if(nrow(OD_Routetable)<2) {
    result[j] <- 100
} else {
    result[j]<-(prd_v==test$route)/nrow(test)*100
}
~~

}
```